# How to use TextInput isFocused() Method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

According to this link in the React Native API Documents:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.59/textinput#isfocused

The TextInput component has a method called isFocused(). How would I go about accessing this method? Do I have to use a ref?

Also, I already know that I can achieve the same effect by using the onFocus prop and setting up a state manager and a function to change the state of the input based on the onFocus. However, I am just curious how I would go about using these component methods since there are others in other components as well.

I have tried using this

```
<TextInput onChangeText={this.handleText} style={(this.isFocused()) ? styles.input : styles.lame} placeholder="Names"/>
```

but it is looking like I might have to use a ref since it seems that it isn't defined even though the method should be a part of this component.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

isFocused() should be called on ref to TextInput.

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import {TextInput, BackHandler} from 'react-native';

function SearchBar() {
  const textInputReference = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    let backhandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      'hardwareBackPress',
      function() {
        if (textInputReference.current.isFocused()) {
          textInputReference.current.blur();
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      },
    );
    return () => {
      backhandler.remove();
    };
  }, []);
  return (
        <TextInput ref={textInputReference} />
  );
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: can this work for dynamic references, like if I am using 20 of input for a custom reference to single Textinput?

Comment: @Prashanttiwari I could not get it clearly. Do you mean there are twenty textinputs and you want all of them to have a single reference?

Answer (score 6):

You can use state for handle input focus, if you have multi-input that also need focus state, just create many state for it.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

   state = { isFocused: false }

   handleInputFocus = () => this.setState({ isFocused: true })

   handleInputBlur = () => this.setState({ isFocused: false })

   render() {
      const { isFocused } = this.state

      return (
        <View>
          <TextInput 
            onFocus={this.handleInputFocus} 
            onBlur={this.handleInputBlur}
            style={ isFocused ? styles.input : styles.lame}
          />
          <Text>Hello World</Text>
        </View>
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: i appreciate it. but I already know how to do it that way like it says in the question. The question was more regarding how to axcess that method listed in the API documentation that belongs to the TextInput  Class

Comment: I have a inputbox with dropdown. When I click the inputbox it shows only the input box above the keyboard and it failed to show the above the keyboard. Keyboard hides the dropdown

Answer (score 3):

This another easy way to use the onFocus prop in TextInput

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native'
    
const TextInput = () => {
  const [isHighlighted, setIsHighlighted] = useState(false)

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        style={[styles.textInput, isHighlighted && styles.isHighlighted]}
        onFocus={() => { setIsHighlighted(true)}
        onBlur={() => {setIsHighlighted(false)} />
      </View>
  )
}
    
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textInput: {
    borderColor: 'grey',
    borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    borderRadius: 8,
    height: 43,
  },
  isHighlighted: {
    borderColor: 'green',
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

[According to its documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#isfocused)

> Returns true if the input is currently focused; false otherwise.

How we can achieve that? the answer is `useRef`.

For example :

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native'

const App = props => {

  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const checkIsFocusedHandler = () => {
    const result = inputRef.current.isFocused();
    alert(result);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

      <TextInput ref={inputRef} style={styles.input} value="Abolfazl Roshanzamir" />
      <TextInput style={styles.input} />

      <Button title="Check isFocused" onPress={checkIsFocusedHandler} />

    </View>
  )
}
```

If we click on the first `TextInput` then click on the button, the result is => **true**,

if we click on the second `TextInput` then click on the button, the result is => **false**.

Answer (score 1):

Use **onFocus** props of TextInput component
`<TextInput onFocus={yourCallBack} />`

**yourCallBack** function will be called when the TextInput  is focused